# How to add values to in the result of while loop in php

Tags: php

How to add the result of the while loop which is stored on the variable $profit? results are 5 and 70

the code

```
  <?php
        $sql2 = "SELECT * from `products`";
        $result2 = $link->query($sql2);

        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
      {

      $sql3 = "SELECT * from `orders` where product_id = '".$row2['prod_id']."'";
      $result3 = $link->query($sql3);
      $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
      
      $sql = "SELECT  SUM(product_qty) from orders where product_id = '".$row2['prod_id']."'";
      $result = $link->query($sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      $res = bcmul($row2['prod_price'], $row[0]);
      $profit = $res - $row2['prod_cost'];

      if($row[0] == null){
          $row[0] = 0;
      }
    }?>
```

Comment: Please add sample data along with the desired result.  There is probably an easier way to do what you want here.

Comment: use a global variable

Comment: Why the nested queries - looks like this could be done with a single query? The `$row3` and `$result3` never get used so why are they there?

Comment: sorry guys I'm still learning php and new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
  <?php
        $sql2 = "SELECT * from `products`";
        $result2 = $link->query($sql2);
        $totalProfit = 0;
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
      {

      $sql3 = "SELECT * from `orders` where product_id = '".$row2['prod_id']."'";
      $result3 = $link->query($sql3);
      $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
      
      $sql = "SELECT  SUM(product_qty) from orders where product_id = '".$row2['prod_id']."'";
      $result = $link->query($sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      $res = bcmul($row2['prod_price'], $row[0]);
      $profit = $res - $row2['prod_cost'];
      $totalProfit = $totalProfit + $profit
      if($row[0] == null){
          $row[0] = 0;
      }
    }?>
```

now you can use `$totalProfit` variable value as total.

Comment: thank you sir Roshan Twanabasu that worked. Others are just criticizing the flow of code and not answering what I am asking. Thank you very much